How do I sort an Excel sheet vertically = reverse the order of the full sheet = put the sheet bottom up = turn the worksheet upside down?
Data in an Excel sheet needs to be sorted the other way round. I cannot sort the data by the two columns date and time since there are some lines in it that do not have the same pattern, for example some groupings with empty cells in the time column.
My aim is to copy blocks of lines from one sheet to another, but in the mirrored order.
Here is a test dataset to work on, thanks to this user:

05.01.2024    10:00
06.01.2024    11:00
07.01.2024    12:00
08.01.2024    13:00
09.01.2024    14:00

This shall become in columns D and E:

How can this be done in MS Excel?

This Q/A is not so far from MS Excel Control sort order of items without using their values, if I read it right. There, the answerer saves a fixed list sort order numbers (row numbers I guess) in a mapping table in another sheet and grabs this with a VLOOKUP().

Why not just use SORTBY() and SEQUENCE() function --> =LET(α, A1:B100, SORTBY(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),-1))

@MayukhBhattacharya You are right, I guess your remark is this answer with the LET() function instead. Perhaps you answer since many do not know the LET() function like me. And your SORTBY() is more understandable for a beginner than the other answer.

You can add the same in your answer. And yes it is simple, to read and understand because you are sorting the array by descending order where -1 means that.

@MayukhBhattacharya I do not want to take that into the step-by-step answer even if they are intertwined. If you put that as a new answer, I choose it.

No its okay, Ron Sir has already given an answer you have accepted the same, you can add the alternative in your answer. I dont mind about that. Its all good.

@MayukhBhattacharya It is about understanding it. When I read yours, I understand it right away. With Ron's, I only thought that it had to be like this in a LET() function. I will change the accepted answer and it is not against Ron's very insightful answer. Still nice how you see it. I do not want to put it
in my answer since that is the "good old way" that everyone can understand at first, but it shall also stay on that level. If you just drop the lines of your remark and do not spend more time on it, that is already enough. It will be overseen in the remarks.

Alright I am posting it as an answer but no need to accept mine, its ok for an upvote. Kindly please no need to accept.

@MayukhBhattacharya Saw this too late, but I also would have disagreed. My question gets the best answer with yours, and all answers will be a win for the readers.

Using Ron Rosenfeld Sir's sample data, one can accomplish the desired output using SORTBY() and SEQUENCE() function:


• Formula used in cell D1
=LET(α, A1:B5, SORTBY(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),-1))

Or in German:
=LET(α; A1:B5; SORTIERENNACH(α;SEQUENZ(ZEILEN(α));-1))



Using LET() function it really makes easier to read and define variables, as well it enhances performances by avoiding redundant calculations.
α is defined for the actual source range which is A1:B5
Using SEQUENCE() and ROWS() we are generating a series of sequential numbers, the latter calculates the numbers of rows in the range while the former helps in generating that number of rows in an array.
Using SORTBY() function to sort the original array by the corresponding array returned by the above in descending order to get the desired output.


NOTE: The above formula is exclusively applicable to MS365 and Excel 2021 users only 

Here is a formula that does not need LET():


=INDEX($A$1:$B$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()),{1,2})

In German:
=INDEX(A$1:A$5;KGRÖSSTE(ZEILE($A$1:$B$5);ZEILE());{1,2})


See here that the second column is greyed out, only then it will work, else check the next:


All of the above formulas do not work below Excel 2021. Thus, if you have Excel 2019 and below (which do not seem to have the feature of that greyed out second column when the formula was entered for the full range), you should try:
=INDEX(A$1:A$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()),{1,2})

In German:
=INDEX(A$1:A$5;KGRÖSSTE(ZEILE($A$1:$B$5);ZEILE());{1,2})

Which is the same as:
=INDEX($A$1:$B$5;LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5);ROW());COLUMN(A1))

In German:
=INDEX($A$1:$B$5;KGRÖSSTE(ZEILE($A$1:$B$5);ZEILE());SPALTE(A1))


Though not needed for the LET() function, the other formulas above need to be entered by triggering the matrix function with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode. And you need to either mark the full cell range before you trigger the formula, or you enter the formula in the first cell only and fill the other cells afterwards by hand.

Mind the last remark. For example, my Office 2019 Professional Plus 2019 does not have the LET function. You can check whether it works in your Excel with =LET(x,1,y,1,x+y), see LET-Funktion - Microsoft.

@questionto42 note already says formulas applicable to MS365 or Excel 2021 and not for older versions.

Misunderstanding. I meant that with "Mind the last remark" (your last remark in the answer). I have only read it after having tried it out the function and wanted to alert anyone overreading it as well.

@questionto42 oh okay sorry.

@questionto42 you could try this in Excel 2019 --> =INDEX($A$1:$B$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()),{1,2}) needs to fill down!

@questionto42 updated formula!

Small thing. The function must be without a dollar before the first column. =INDEX(A$1:$B$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()),{1,2}). The rest of the dollars can stay. And you do not need to write "Updated Formula" since this is a formula for <v2021, not just an update to the other since the other is the best choice if you have v2021.

@questionto42 not necessary. It has to keep the all dollars!

I have just tested it on my own dataset and then on this test dataset. Your formula works only in the rows, it stays the first column all the time. If you drop the very first dollar, it works.

@questionto42 not sure why it works on my end. Have you entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode? You can see here

Yes, I know that "matrix triggering Enter", and I did it like that so that you see the curly brackets in each cell. Yet, I see that your second column is greyed out so that you seem to do it in another way. While I entered the formula in the first cell and filled it down and to the right, you seem to have marked all cells to run the matrix function in one go by filling the formula in the first cell but running it on the full range by that. Trying that fails for me, but I see that it works for you. Must be the 2019 Excel again.

@questionto42 then use this simple: =INDEX(A$1:A$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()))

Works. Yes, that makes it clearer now that you just tell Excel 2019 then in which column you are, kind of a column counter that you can begin with column A regardless of where your range's firsts column is.

@questionto42 yes exactly, to make shorter i did it in that way, you can also use this: =INDEX($A$1:$B$5,LARGE(ROW($A$1:$B$5),ROW()),COLUMN(A1))

Formulas in German: =INDEX($A$1:$B$5;KGRÖSSTE(ZEILE($A$1:$B$5);ZEILE());SPALTE(A1)), =INDEX(A$1:A$5;KGRÖSSTE(ZEILE($A$1:$B$5);ZEILE());{1,2})

@questionto42 if you want can edit post and write the formula for German users it will helps =) Thank you very much!

If you have 365, you can do this with a single formula in a single cell:I use the LET function for readability
E1: =LET(
    data, $A$1:$B$5,
    seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data), , ROWS(data), -1),
    CHOOSEROWS(data, seq)
)

Or in German:
E1: =LET(
    data; $A$1:$B$5;
    seq; SEQUENZ(ZEILEN(data); ;ZEILEN(data); -1);
    ZEILENWAHL(data; seq)
)



Or shorter: CHOOSEROWS(data, -SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)))

@phipsgabler Yes, it is. And as I wrote, "I use the LET function for readability"

@phipsgabler The function does not work in Excel below 2021. Thus, for a version below 2021, I have to take my old-school answer.

@phipsgabler I tested it in Office365, works, it could be another answer even if it is technically the same, for those who want to avoid LET() to make it still readable for third parties without that knowledge. In German, it is =ZEILENWAHL($A$1:$B$5; -SEQUENZ(ZEILEN($A$1:$B$5))).

This is good old handicraft if you are below Excel 2021 or do not work in Office 365.
Make a helper column next to the data range and write down in the first cell next to the range:
=ROW()
You will see the row number of the cell. Then fill this formula down to the bottom and mark the whole column.
Here, it is =ZEILE() in German:

Copy and paste the numbers as values, for example, press CtrlAltV or do it by another way.
Werte = Values:

Now you have the numbers in a new column so that they can be "sorted backwards":

Makes:

